# react-router handling requests to routes in client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, client-side, react-router

I am new to react and react-router and am playing around with it.  It is nice, but I am wondering the how to get the requests made to myapp.com/myroute work, other than when I navigate around.  Whenever i reload a page with a route in it it says 'cannot GET' ... I understand this is because the server is not handling that route, so I am wondering what the best way is to handle this?  Say I am using node.  Would it be to write methods for each route on the server and then somehow return the app at the state where that route is present?  Is there a way to have the server send all requests to the client and then have the client dictate which client route based on the request? I am wondering what the best way is to approach this, making the client side routes active in all scopes.

Thanks to all in advanced!!!

Comment: Hi there. Great job so far. This is absolutely a SERVER question and not react. You DO need your server to serve assets no matter which route is requested. At that point you can have react start to pickup where it left off.

Comment: Thank you so much Blair!  I thought so.  So with a react/single page app, my node server just servers a static file, and responds with the entire single page app.  Given my structure (node express static server, react single page app using react-router) how should I handle requests on the server to accommodate the routes in the client? should I not serve the app statically? Once I handle the request properly will react router do the rest of the work?

Comment: yes, kinda. You will do most of the work :) but you'll use react router to find the correct route and activate the corresponding component.

Comment: @BlairAnderson I disagree, this is very much a react-router question, as anyone using the router no doubt has to deal with this issue.  With how much the router is used there has to be common solutions people use...i just can't find them yet.  (Guessing having the server respond with the same page at all requests except the static assets or something?)